# fgets inside the while loop

Tags: c, fgets

I'm having an issue with `fgets` because it is returning `\n` on the first time it enters the `while` loop right after the `k` input.
Since I'm already inside the `while` loop and my `#1 try` as already been written, how do I deal with this?

```
int main() {
    char r;

    printf("How to input?\n");
    printf("Keyboard ([K])\n File ([F])\n Leave ([E])\n");
    scanf("%c", &r);

    if (r == 'k' || r == 'K') {
        printf("\nKeyboard\n");
        opcaoTeclado();
    } else {
       // stuff
    }
}

void opcaoTeclado() {
    int try = 0;
    char inputline[161];

    while (try <= 10) {
        printf("\n#%d try\n ", try);
        fgets(inputline, 160, stdin);
        try++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the call to `scanf()`, there's a newline in the input which is read by the first call `fgets()`. [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) stops reading input when it encounters a newline `\n`. Hence, it doesn't read any input.

Add a call to `getchar();` right after `scanf()` to consume the newline.

Or you can also use a loop to consume if there are multiple chars in the input.

```
int c;

while((c= getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

In general, it's best to avoid mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()`. You can use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` and parse the line using `sscanf()` which is less prone.

Answer (score 1):

You should clean stdin's buffer. You can do it using `fflush(stdin);` before your loop. But it's a bad style. Consider also `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);`.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is *undefined behaviour* in standard C. Although it works on certain platforms, it should be avoided.

Comment: Both are bad solutions.  The OP could just write `if (r != '\n') { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') continue; }` to *flush* the current line.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add as space after format to consume the `\n`

```
scanf("%c ", &r);
```

Comment: No, this is a bad idea since it would keep waiting for non space input.

Comment: @chqrlie I agree, but is ok for OP case.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not. Further non space input from the user would be required **before** the test on `'k'` could proceed.  I don't think that's the expected behavior.  The `if (r != '\n') { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') continue; }` solution is much better.

Answer (score 1):

1. > I'm having an issue with fgets because it is returning \n on the first time it enters the while loop right after the "k" input.

   That's because for `scanf("%c", &r);` when you enter `k[ENTER_KEY]`, the character `k` gets stored in variable `r` leaving the `\n` (ENTER key pressed) in the `stdin` stream.

   So for `fgets(inputline, 160, stdin);`, it finds the `\n` newline character in `stdin`, stoes it in `inputline` and exits as from `man -s3 fgets`:

   > fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.

---

2. > Since I'm already inside the while loop and my "#1 try" as already been written, how do I deal with this?

   You can consume that `\n` in `stdin` by using `getchar()`